# Create a table with required & optional checkbox columns & check-one only columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need create a table containing check-boxes with a few specific needs for an e-mail feature.
(Yes, I know radio buttons have this feature for choosing either or, but it's not what I'm looking to have done.)

This table has about 11 columns and a X amount of rows:

- First column contains E-mail addresses.
- The second is blank for dividing the rest of it for another purpose,
  maybe an button, etc.
- The next columns are filled with check-boxes in which 4 have special
  requirements:

  - Columns 4 & 5 can only have one or the other check-box ticked in
    (i.e. if column 4 has a check, then column 5 is unchecked and vice
    versa).  The code I have found here works, but the option remains
    checked; not allowing the user to ***not*** choose between the two.
  - Columns 8 & 9 are optional/required check-boxes
    (i.e. if column 9 is checked, then so is column 8. However, column 8 can be checked
    without column 9 checked.

I've gotten some other code for another section of the page (with similar requirements, but not in a table) that might be worth making the table's code a bit more flexible to include the entire page for the other single instances of those check-boxes.

I've made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gayeke/edit?html,js,output) of what I've tried to make so far (also pieced from other questions here), but I'm stumped at making it search per row for just those elements.

http://jsbin.com/gayeke/edit?html,js,output